# Get first adress of cell having value in 2D array

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumproduct

I have a 2D array on Excel, with values which could be repeating.

On another cell I have a value.
Now I want to get the address  of the first cell of my 2d array which has same value.
By first cell I mean the first on a reading-basis, from left to right and up to down.

If there were only distinct value I could do something like

```
=SUMPRODUCT((AF26:AK30=W35)*ROW(AF26:AK30))

=SUMPRODUCT((AF26:AK30=W35)*COLUMN(AF26:AK30))
```

First formula is for the row, second for the column.

But it doesn’t work on repeating value.
Do you know how I could do?

Answer (score 2):

Alternative:

```
=LET(
    ζ,AF26:AK30,
    @TOCOL(IF(ζ=W35,ADDRESS(ROW(ζ),COLUMN(ζ)),NA()),2)
)
```

Comment: Wonderful. Reminds me of VBA's `On Error Resume Next`.

Answer (score 1):

This puts the range into a column and then MATCH returns its position in that column.  Then with INT and MOD we find the row and column.

```
=LET(
    rng,AF26:AK30,
    pos,MATCH(W35,TOCOL(rng), 0)-1,
    clm,COLUMNS(rng),
    ADDRESS(INT(pos/clm)+MIN(ROW(rng)),MOD(pos,clm)+MIN(COLUMN(rng))))
```

[image]

Comment: I think you should either be passing a *match_type* parameter of 0 to `MATCH` or else using `XMATCH`. I get incorrect results when `TOCOL(rng)` does not coincidentally happen to be sorted ascendingly, as in your example.

Comment: Thanks for the formula, but it doesn’t work, it returns the last one and not the first one. On the example, you have only one 10, if you write a second one you’ll see it returns the second one.

Comment: @ImFabien75 see edit. Jos was correct

Answer (score 1):

### Address of First Match (ByRows)

```
=LET(d,AF26:AK30,v,W35,
    c,COLUMNS(d),
    m,XMATCH(v,TOCOL(d)),
    ar,INDEX(ROW(d),INT((m-1)/c)+1),
    ac,INDEX(COLUMN(d),,MOD(m-1,c)+1),
IFERROR(ADDRESS(ar,ac),""))
```

```
d - the range
v - the lookup value
c - the number of columns
m - the row index of the match in the 'TOCOL' column
ar - the matching worksheet row
ac - the matching worksheet column
```

```
ROW(d) - a vertical array of all the range (worksheet) rows
COLUMN(d) - a horizontal array of all the range (worksheet) columns
```